SPO "stuck" folders with ProgID Team.Channel
The issue
After a tenant migration from Teams to SharePoint, all data is accessible except for the folders that were previously private channels in Teams. These folders are now stuck and cannot be deleted or edited; they seem to be in read-only mode.
Left is the expected menu, but the one on the right are the previously private channels within Teams
Different ProgId value
Cause/Difference
When looking at the extended properties from these folders there is a difference in the "ProgID" key value. Then I try to change the value to "SharePoint.DocumentSet" (because $null is invalid)
$Folders = Get-PnPFolderItem -Identity "Gedeelde documenten" | select Name,progID

foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    if ($Folder.progID -eq "Team.Channel") {
        Set-PnPPropertyBagValue -Key "progID" -Value "SharePoint.DocumentSet"
        Get-PnPPropertyBag -Key "progID"
    }
}

With 2 different commands I get 2 different outputs:
The first command returns "SharePoint.DocumentSet" as expected while changing the value:
Get-PnPPropertyBag -Key "progID"
The second command is still showing "Team.Channel" so the folder is still in read-only mode:
Get-PnPFolderItem -Identity "Gedeelde documenten" | select name,progID
Still the wrong value
I might need to raise a ticket with Microsoft. Has anyone else experienced this before?

You can login and change permissions : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

The permissions are correct and inherited from the site (security groups). Files and subfolders from the root folder can also be managed. The problem is the 'channelfolder'. Normally, you can solve this issue when you remove the channel from Teams, but because of the migration, there is no Teams anymore.

The folders have to be coming from some place.  If you do not have Teams, than the folder must be in the Share Point.

The folders were Teams channels in the source tenant. All folders are working fine in the destination tenant except the channels which were private in the source tenant. It was a Tenant-to-Tenant migration from Teams -> SharePoint Only.
"After a tenant migration from Teams to SharePoint, all data is accessible except for the folders that were previously private channels in Teams."

Those folders are now in the Share Point.  Where else would they come from?   If they are in Share Point, then the link I provided should help remove them.
