Assigning Teams Policy to a group using Powershell
I'm attempting to use powershell to build a script that will pull a lit of users from an AzureAD Group and assign a Teams Policy to them.
$group = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "Test Group" 
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true | Where-Object {$_.ObjectType -eq "User"} 
New-CsBatchPolicyAssignmentOperation -PolicyType TeamsAppPermissionPolicy -PolicyName "Test Policy" -Identity $members.UserPrincipalName

Getting the following error:
New-CsBatchPolicyAssignmentOperation : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Identity' because it is null.
At line:1 char:117
+ ...  -PolicyName "Test Policy" -identity $members.UserPrincipleName
+                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-CsBatchPolicyAssignmentOperation], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,New-CsBatchPolicyAssignmentOperation


I don't have answer.  This may be a PS bug.  Looks very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78962016/spo-stuck-folders-with-progid-team-channel#comment139223917_78962016

Hi @Justin Any update on issue?

I observed that you are using -identity $members.UserPrincipleName which has typo error in fetching User principal names of group members.
Initially, I too got same error when I ran the script passing same typo as you like this:
$group = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "groupname" 
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true | Where-Object {$_.ObjectType -eq "User"} 
New-CsBatchPolicyAssignmentOperation -PolicyType TeamsAppPermissionPolicy -PolicyName "Test Policy"  -identity $members.UserPrincipleName

Response:

To resolve the error, make sure to run the script without any typos by passing $members.UserPrincipalName as -Identity value like this:
$group = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "groupname" 
$members = Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $group.ObjectId -All $true | Where-Object {$_.ObjectType -eq "User"} 
New-CsBatchPolicyAssignmentOperation -PolicyType TeamsAppPermissionPolicy -PolicyName "Test Policy" -Identity $members.UserPrincipalName

Response:

